# Retrofit not returning ETag and Last-Modified

Tags: php, android, header, retrofit, etag

I want ETag to get the newer version of the cache made by retrofit in the android studio. I have tried using different using a different header but that doesn't seem to work.

```
public static final String HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL = "Cache-Control";
public static final String HEADER_PRAGMA = "Pragma"; 
return response.newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader(HEADER_PRAGMA)
                    .removeHeader(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL)
                    .header("Cache-Control:", "private, must-revalidate")//cacheControl.toString())
                    .build();
```

Comment: Is this question about PHP?

Comment: It's about Android and I am using retrofit

Comment: Remove the incorrect tags then